# Adding Images iOS xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, image

So I'm trying to convert one of my Android apps to iOS. In android we just have a drawable folder to store Images in. I'm pretty new to iOS and xCode and I was trying to find something similar here, however I didn't so I simply created an images folder and added all my resources to it. I added a button and set the background property to one of the images I added. [image]

This works fine in the display in xCode however when I run this in the simulator, I get the following error:

```
2016-03-20 00:31:20.617 City[588:12453] Could not load the "btn_back_rev.jpg" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "citylife.City"
```

Here is the image:

[image]

and the way it is referenced in the Main.Storyboard :

```
<resources>
    <image name="btn_back_rev.jpg" width="320" height="60"/>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you created, as you say, an images *folder*. What you should have done is to create an images *group* in project navigator (choose New > Group) and drag your images from the Finder into that group in the project navigator.

The reason this works is that the group is just virtual. Thus the images themselves end up at the top level of the built app bundle, and that is where the storyboard expects them to be. The folder, on the other hand, was a real folder and so your images were in a folder one level deep in the app bundle, and the storyboard couldn't find them.

Comment: It's not letting me drag anything into the group I created

Comment: Hang in there, I have a slow connection, still uploading.

Comment: Yep it works, I just assumed that when it shows the line under Images its gonna add them below it, instead of putting it inside the folder, that's why I thought its not working

Comment: It sounds like you are new not only to iOS and Xcode but to Macs. You have a lot to get used to! :)

Comment: Hahaha yes I'm running a virtual machine where I'm coding this. I got the finished version in android on windows and about a month to translate it to iOS.

Comment: Cool! I didn't even know that was possible. I thought you had to have a physical Mac.

Answer (score 0):

because you haven't add the Images folder to the targets,you can move the Images folder to Assets.xcassets.