# Image views and buttons not appearing in the simulator

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview, uibutton

When I run my app on xcode, my image views and buttons wont appear in the simulations. They show up in the storyboard, but, they do not show up in the simulation. My buttons and image views have images, and they are png files. I haven't put any serious code in the app yet because I wanted to make sure the Image views and buttons were appearing (sadly they did not appear :( ). The only code I put in were IBOutlets for the Image Views and IBActions for the buttons (Non of which have any code inside yet). I am currently running xcode 7.3.1 and new to the swift language.

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5doMT.png)

// Here is the code from the view controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var SlotRectangle1: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var SlotRectangle2: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var SlotRectangle3: UIImageView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func SlotButton1() {
    }

    @IBAction func SlotButton2() {
    }

    @IBAction func SlotButton3() {
    }
}
```

Comment: You are getting a crash according to the storyboard... What crash is it?

Answer (score 0):

From the error messages, it looks like you either didn't add the image assets correctly, or perhaps didn't add them at all.

Check out the answer here: [Adding Images iOS xCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109168/adding-images-ios-xcode)